# Can hedgehogs travel frequently?

Tags: travel

I am considering buying a hedgehog. My hesitation is that about once a month I travel about four hours away by car to visit my dad. I usually leave late Thursday night and return Sunday late afternoon. Would a hedgehog be ok in a traveling crate for that long? Will the traveling be too stressful for him? Or, alternatively, would he be ok if left alone with food and water for that time?

Answer (score 1):

Travelling is fine, chances are he/she will be sleeping the entire time. I would recommend bringing her regular cage with you so she can stay in it during your visit, being cooped up in a travel crate wouldn't be very fun for her.

You can also leave her alone for the time and top up food and water though I would recommend having someone stop by in between to make sure she doesn't run out of anything, specifically water. Sometimes those bottles drip depleting the water supply very quickly.